# Enviar un Objeto a un Servicio WCF

Tags: c#, asp.net, windows-forms, wcf

quisiera saber si existe alguna forma de mandar un objeto a un servicio ***WCF***

### el programa que envia esta en ***WindowsForm c#***

### el que recibe esta en ***asp.net c#***

```
        OleDbConnection connection = MSAConnection.getConnection();

        string sql = @"SELECT 
                        cod as cod,
                        Format(fecha, 'Short Date') as fecha,
                        Format(hora, 'Short Time') as hora,
                        1 as Tipo
                FROM Control";

        OleDbDataAdapter d = new OleDbDataAdapter(sql, connection);
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        d.Fill(dt);
        dataGridView1.DataSource = dt;

        var Control= (from rw in dt.AsEnumerable()
                          select new DatosModelObj()
                          {
                              cod = Convert.ToInt32(rw["cod"]),
                              fecha = Convert.ToDateTime(rw["fecha"]),
                              hora = Convert.ToDateTime(rw["hora"]),
                              Tipo = Convert.ToInt32(rw["Tipo"])
                          }).ToList();

        WebRequest request = WebRequest.Create(@"http://localhost:77777/Services/Control.svc/Control/" + Control);
        request.Credentials = CredentialCache.DefaultCredentials;
        WebResponse response = request.GetResponse();
        Stream dataStream = response.GetResponseStream();
        StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(dataStream);
        reader.Close();
        response.Close();
```

***MI SERVICIO***

```
namespace Registro.Services
{
    [ServiceContract]
    public interface IControl
    {
        [OperationContract]
        [WebGet(UriTemplate = "Control/{Control}",
                RequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json,
                ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json)]
        List<ControlModel> GetRegistro(ControlModel Control);
    }
}
```

Comment: Hola, sabes que en un `GET` no se debería enviar un objeto? Te recomiendo lo cambies a un servicio que reciba un `POST` empleado para ello `[WebInvoke] ` en vez de  `[WebGet]`

Answer (score 1):

¿es necesario enviar el objeto a través de un **Json**? ya que noto que tienes tu **GetRegistro** con la etiqueta **"RequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json"**. De cualquier forma ¿has utilizado los **Service References**? te dejo un ejemplo sencillo ya que puedes enviar objectos definidos en tu servicio WCF (los **DataContract**) desde tu aplicación WebForms.

Para el ejemplo utilice dos proyectos uno LittleClient (app de consola) y LittleService (app WCF Service).

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

LittleService contiene un **DataContract** llamado **Student** (que es el objeto que se enviara desde el cliente) y un **OperationContract** (que es el método que consumiremos en el cliente)

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

En la aplicación de consola (LittleClient) agregamos un ServiceReference de nuestro servicio WCF, esto se hace clic derecho en el proyecto/Add/Service Rerefence.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Si el servicio esta en el mismo proyecto puedes pulsar el botón **discover**, si no puedes agregar el link donde se encuentre tu servicio **WCF**

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Notaras que ahora tienes una carpeta llamada Service References y en ella la referencia a tu servicio WCF.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

A continuación creamos el objeto que tiene definido el servicio (es decir el datacontract Student)

Finalmente para hacer la llamada al método desde tu cliente (winforms,consola,etc) creas una instancia del cliente que viene en el service references **"LittleServiceReference.Service1Client"**.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Finalmente el resultado es que el servicio recibe el objeto Student cuando el cliente realiza la llamada al metodo CreateStudent:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Este es el objeto que recibe el servicio Web:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Y aquí esta la respuesta del servicio en el cliente:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Si te sirve la respuesta házmelo saber si no también xd

Saludos cordiales.